# Calculate Heuristics for graph

Tags: artificial-intelligence, heuristics

I have these Information for a graph:

- number of vertices
- edges with weight

**and Nothing more**. and I want to calculate a heuristic for each vertices so I can use a path finding algorithm like A Star. What can I do? If you know more than one solution please mention all of them.

Please note that I can't calculate Manhattan distance and use it as a heuristic because I don't have any location Information .

Answer (score 0):

You can still use A* but you will have to "cheat" a little.  A* is an extension of Dijkstra's Shortest Path algorithm.  The extension is that A* uses a distance heuristic to keep the search going in the right direction.  Given a graph with just weight edges you calculate the shortest sum of weights from node n to the goal node and use that as the heuristic distance.  So the distance from START to Target is 8, the distance from A to TARGET is 7, distance(B, TARGET) = 2 and so forth.  Since this is a heuristic you could also use other measurements.  If you set the distances to 0 then this becomes Dijkstra's algorithm.  If you set the distances high then this turns into the Greedy-Best-First algorithm.

[image: Example Graph]